# iPhone - in-App purchase consumable correct approach

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have this new app I am creating that will use consumable in-app purchases.

My question is this: how does that work? I mean, imagine the user buys a consumable stuff. So, after finalizing the sell I set a flag on the app's database authorizing the use of that object. I read somewhere that I have to provide the user with a button to restore old transactions in case of the user for some reason loses his device and has to restore everything.

Imagine the user has already used that purchase and after that he restores the old in-app purchases. What happens then? Will the user have the same resources again, so he can use a second time without paying? How it works and how should I approach that?

thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I wanted to share a somewhat unorthodox solution I found to this problem that has the HUGE advantage of not requiring a server. This method allows users to restore their consumable items if the app is deleted and reinstalled, but does not allow them to move the items to a new device (unless all their app data is copied over).

Data stored in the keychain persists when an app is deleted and reinstalled. The keychain is intended for storing usernames and passwords, but you can also store information about consumable purchases in there. I used the KeychainItemWrapper class, available here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Here is some sample code where I store and retrieve the number of paid hints that a user has remaining:

```
//Storing the consumable hint item count
int hintsLeft = 100;
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Hints" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *hintsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",hintsLeft];
[wrapper setObject:hintsString forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
[wrapper release];

//Retrieving it
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Hints" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *numHints = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
[wrapper release];
int retrievedHints = [numHints intValue];
```

Notes:

- the key (id)kSecValueData can't be an arbitrary string, there is a set list of constants that you can use as the key.
- You will need to add the security framework

Comment: This is the kind of post I wish I could upvote twice.  Excellent, creative persistent solution to a perennial problem.  I had this working in 15 minutes, and highly recommend the approach for tracking consumables.

Comment: But I assume, if the user restores his device as new, the IAP consumables would be lost. Wouldn't that be a problem and result in annoyed users?

Comment: This is great solution!! But now you can get allow them to move a new device for iOS 7 too – use iCloud + Keychain sync (kSecAttrSyncronizable)

Comment: So `kSecValueData` must be unique for each consumable purchase. How do we get a value for that? Are we storing the whole iap data in kSecValueData ? Or when you restore in app purchases does Apple provide a unique ID for each consumable? (In case they buy the consumable 13 times). How does this work?

Comment: Albert Renshaw you can store a JSON encoded array or dictionary in kSecValueData instead of just the information for one consumable purchase.

Comment: Hi, I'm using this solution as well and it works nicely. However, I assume there will be problems when 1) Users log-in to their icloud keychain with a separate account from their appstore account (which is possible, see iOS Settings) and 2) By using consumables on two devices, how can device B (let's say it's entirely offline) know how many consumables (of the same account) were consumed on device A? (without restricting use of consumables when a device is offline)

Comment: Using the keychain for this purpose (not username/password), will I need to document export compliance?

Comment: There are too many problems with this solution like @pille mentioned. If apple reviewer rejects your app for this stupid reason then appeal the rejection. We just cannot implement "restore" feature for a consumable purchase.

Comment: For info: `pod 'AppleGenericKeychain'`

Comment: 2024, still works. Use a keychain lib, and a singleton manager class to maintain the consumable count and methods for mutating that count. Pretty simple code and effective against re-installs. No login, no usertracking, no backend needed.

Alternative to keychain is to use SwiftData model container synced on icloud, or using NSUbiqitiousKeyValue but both of these alternatives require iCloud to be enabled and break if user disables icloud.

Answer (score 29):

StoreKit only provides recovery functionality for non-consumable items (and to some extend for subscriptions). So for consumable products, recovering using `restoreCompletedTransactions` will not deliver any transactions in your case. Any handling of restoring information about consumable products must be done within your app and/or server.

For reference of the various products' natures check the [In App Purchase Programming Guide:Designing Your App’s Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2). There are **Consumable** products which must be purchased each time, **Non-consumable** products purchased only once and provided to all devices associated with that user’s iTunes account, **Auto-Renewable** subscriptions and **Non-Renewing** Subscriptions

Comment: that what I was suspecting. Thanks.

Comment: Marcus and Robot, What do u refer to as consumable and non-consumable in case in-app-purchase?

Comment: @Krishnan The Apple documentation epxlains all these terms. Check the [In App Purchase Programming Guide:Registering Products with the App Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW11). There are **Consumable** products which must be purchased each time, **Non-consumable** products purchased only once and provided to all devices associated with that user’s iTunes account, **Auto-Renewable subscriptions** and **Non-Renewing Subscriptions**

Comment: This is the correct answer. there is no "restore" feature for consumable in-app purchases. Apple will not reject your app for this reason. If they do then submit an appeal. It happened to me and they agreed that restore doesn't make sense for consumable in-app

Comment: @marcus your link is dead. This one seems better. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: Add a link to the official documentation (with content to avoid link rot) and I'll remove my downvote. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2 "Consumable products, by their nature, aren’t synced or restored."

Answer (score 5):

For people who come hare searching for the way to store consumable items locally in iOS, have a look at PDKeychainBindingsController (https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController).

It works like NSUserDefaults and can be used to store the purchased consumable item count in iDevice's keychain (the items stored in keychain do not get removed while deleting the app.).

Use the code something like below to store and retrieve the value from keychain:

```
- (NSUInteger)hintCount {
    PDKeychainBindings *wrapper=[PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings];
    NSString *valueString = [wrapper objectForKey:@"hintCount"];
    int value = [valueString intValue];
    return value;
}

- (void)setHintCount:(NSUInteger)starCount {
    PDKeychainBindings *wrapper=[PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings];
    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",starCount];
    [wrapper setObject:valueString forKey:@"hintCount"];
}
```