# Consumable In-App Purchase and Restore Button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

The Restore IAP button is required to all apps now, and if they don't have Apple will reject the app.

The questions is, what about consumable items? It seems logical that you can't restore them, since the user will spend the extra coins on the game and that's it.

I'm storing the coins using NSUserDefaults, so if the user deletes the app he will lose everything, unless he syncs through iTunes. iCloud backup to sync devices will be added in a future update, but I guess this has nothing to do with the question, that is...

Consumable IAP can/must be restored?

I'm just afraid of getting a rejection and delay even more my new game.

Thanks,

Comment: I found the great solution to restore consumable purchases http://stackoverflow.com/a/9102416/1180406

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consumables are not to be restored, just as you were reasoning in your original question.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer. Now if anyone else has the same question it will find here :)

Comment: Is this still true? what about an app that only sells consumable items, is the restore purchases button required anyways?

Comment: well noone answered my comment, but I already know, it is NOT required, if someone ever has the doubt.

Comment: Is there official documentation about this? Please edit your answer to include official documentation and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 8):

From Apple's [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)

> Consumable products, by their nature, aren’t synced or restored. Users
>   understand that, for example, buying ten more bubbles on their iPhone
>   doesn’t also give them ten more bubbles on their iPad. All other types
>   of products are made available across all of the user’s devices.
>   They’re also restored so users can continue to access their purchased
>   content even after buying a new device. StoreKit handles the syncing
>   and restoring process for auto-renewable subscriptions and for
>   non-consumable products.

Answer (score 1):

Consumable items are not to be restored. If you want to deliver content from server, make transaction as finished only after delivering content from server. **The receipt will be only available until you mark the transaction as finished.**