# Restoring in-app consumable purchases

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

This is more of a quick question. I have never released an app with in-app purchasing before and I cannot find this information anywhere. I know that you can get rejected from the store for not having a restore completed transactions option. Obviously this makes sense for non-consumables, but for consumables is it a requirement? Because if i sold someone some in-game currency they could just use it then get a refund straight after which would be nonsensical.

Comment: The qualified answer here is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449312/iphone-in-app-purchase-consumable-correct-approach?rq=1

Comment: No need 'Restore Purchase' option for consumable purchases. Read more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase