# How to detect if user has made any in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My iOS app has in-app purchases (consumable) and shows ads periodically. The idea is to remove ads after user has purchased anything. But in-app items are consumable, so after user re-installs the app, I would be unable to determine if he has purchased anything using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`, right? And I would bomb him with ads again...

What would you suggest to find out that the user has purchased anything already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when a user re-installs your app (i.e. delete it and install it again) there is no immediate way of knowing what purchases did he made. That's why Apple requires your app to provide a way to restore previous purchases so that when the user performs this operation he restores these purchases for free.

For consumable items you might need to use a server for managing the purchases such that when the app loads it checks with the server which purchases the user has made and immediately enable the relevant content.

I do not know if mandatory but "Remove Ads" IAP should be non-consumable so the user will only need to purchase it once (Otherwise I believe users will complain or just won't buy it).

Some creative ways can be found here : [iPhone - in-App purchase consumable correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449312/iphone-in-app-purchase-consumable-correct-approach)

Comment: I think the problem is there is no "Remove Ads" in-app-purchase, but he removes adds whenever anything, including a consumable item, is purchased.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on the situation, you could store the fact that a purchase was made in NSUserDefaults. That won't survive if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, but at least it survives if the user buys a new phone and restores a backup to transfer everything to the new phone.

You could have a look at Cloud Kit as well, which would store information per AppleId. It's a bit overkill for the problem, but it means you can use Apple's servers instead of your own for free. There would be a difference that if a user installs your app on six devices, makes a consumable purchase on one device, ads will stop on all of them.

Comment: Storing receipts in user defaults is risky as it can be easily editable . However there is a way to secure it : https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults